# Я хочу вывести ФИО сотрудников на comboBox1 чтобы не вводить вручную Используя context entity-framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я вывел целую таблицу на грид

```
 context db;//
       public  FruitStoragePresenter()
        {
            context db = new context();
            var fruit = new FruitS<FruitStorage>(db.FuitStorages); 
            fruit.Show();
            db.Sotrs.
```

но не знаю как вывести одно поле на combo box

Answer (score 0):

```
  context m;
        private void comboBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            InsertFruit insertFruit = new InsertFruit();
            m = new context();
            comboBox1.DataSource = m.Sotrs.ToList();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Fio";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Kod_sotr";
        }
```